# How to prevent PyCharm from automatically closing opened files?

Tags: configuration, pycharm

From time to time I need to open multiple files in PyCharm. Every opened file has a visible tab on the top of the editor. From my observations when the visible tabs take the space of two rows PyCharm starts to automatically close the files opened first. How can I prevent this? Often I really need to open the files that PyCharm automatically closes and my productivity drops immediately!

Comment: The worst part is when you don't notice and finish all the edits on what you think is all the required files.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Windows: `Settings` | `Editor` | `General` | `Editor Tabs` | **Tab limit**

Mac: `Preferences` | `Editor` | `General` | `Editor Tabs` | **Tab limit**

Under the `Tab Closing Policy` group, the default is 10, set it to some larger value.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you CrazyCoder!